# TypeError in Bolt CMS

Tags: javascript, json, bolt-cms

I wanted to install extensions in the bolt admin interface. As soon as I open the page it gets my this error:

> An unknown error occurred. This was the error message: `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Lookin at the console of the page I get:

> `TypeError: n.error is undefined [Learn More] bolt.js:9:20734` 
>   n > http://localhost/bolt-public/js/bolt.js:9:20734 
>   o/ http://localhost/bolt-public/js/bolt.js:9:23517 
>   l > http://localhost/bolt-public/js/lib.js:1:37033 
>   fireWith > http://localhost/bolt-public/js/lib.js:1:37801 
>   r > http://localhost/bolt-public/js/lib.js:1:74124 
>   n/< > http://localhost/bolt-public/js/lib.js:1:79953

In this file I found:

```
/**
 * These are Bolt’s COMPILED JS files!
 * Do not edit this file, because all changes will be lost. You can edit the 
 * `*.js` files in `app/src/js/` and then run `yarn grunt updateBolt` to generate 
 * this file. You will need to use the "Clone the Git Repository" installation method, to 
 * get these files. See: https://docs.bolt.cm/core-development/install-git-clone, 
 * as well as the `README.md` file in the `app/src/` folder.
 */
```

So what can I do besides install the extensions manually? If I go this way I can't update Bolt either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused by a low-level exception, the latest release from just before Christmas has updates to the JavaScript to be a bit more informative about what is really going on.

Comment: Can I update these parts specifically or do I have to setup the whole project?

Comment: You can run `composer update bolt/bolt` and that will take care of it